# Remove multiple deleted items at once from Git - Command line

Tags: git

How do I delete multiple "deleted" files at once through the Command Line? After I add more files to git with the command:

```
git add .
```

Some files need to be removed from git like the ones that have been deleted under the caption `Changes not staged for commit:` after running the command `git status`

```
 deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/winter.js
 deleted:    app/views/comments/create.js.coffee
 deleted:    app/views/designs/index.json.jbuilder
```

And I have about 25 of those files that need to be removed. Right now, the only way I know how to is to delete each individually with:

```
git rm app/assets/javascripts/winter.js
```

How can I delete all of these with one command?? just to make my life easier.

Comment: Is the "deleted:" output from git status?

Comment: The question shows a list of files prefixed with the string "deleted: ".  Is that output cut-and-paste from git status or some other command?

Comment: Yea cut and paste from a `git status`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this I use:

```
git add -u .
```

From git man pages:

> Only match  against already tracked files in the index
>   rather than the working tree. That means that it will never stage new
>   files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files
>   **and that it will remove files from the index if the corresponding files in the working tree have been removed**.
>
> If no  is given, default to "."; in other words, update
>   all tracked files in the current directory and its subdirectories.

This will also stage any tracked files with changes but won't add new files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just bash syntax, you can do something like:

```
git rm app/{assets/javascripts/winter.js,views/comments/create.js.coffee,views/designs/index.json.jbuilder}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a one-line bash "script", e.g.,

```
git status | awk '/deleted: / { printf "git rm %s\n", $2 }' | sh -x
```

To test that it's going to do what you expect, leave the `| sh -x` off the end so it just prints the commands out.

Comment: This pattern will include files staged for deletion and not just files deleted from the workspace. `git ls-files -dz | xargs -0 rm` is less to type, doesn't have said limitation, and copes with filenames with spaces and other characters that might upset the shell.

Comment: @ChrisCleeland, you _can_ upvote a comment. Hover over on the left and you'll see an arrow appear.

Comment: @MagnusBäck, that almost works, but when I run that line, a ` seems to appear before the path and I get "no such file or directory" for each resource that would otherwise be deleted.

Comment: @JakeParis: That's weird. What if you replace `rm` with `echo`?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Running `git ls-files -dz | xargs -0 echo` gets `bar.txt foo.txt foob.txt foobar.txt`. Running `git ls-files -dz | xargs -0 rm` gets `rm: cannot remove \`bar.txt': No such file or directory` for each file. Note the 2 different types of quote around the resource name

Comment: Oh. Never mind the quotes, they're part of the error message. The real problem is a bug in my previous comment; the command should be `xargs -0 git rm`, not `xargs -0 rm`.